# Windows 10 bash apt update service disable

Tags: windows, bash, apt

I'm using Windows 10 and Bash on Windows 10.

Can I disable automatic apt-get update? It's annoying when I play game and it's updating because my screen freeze for 3 seconds. It happends every 15 - 30 minutes or something like that.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
sudo apt remove unattended-upgrades
```

In cmd:

```
schtasks.exe /Delete /TN “\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Subsystem for Linux\AptPackageIndexUpdate”
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/6jl13h/even_on_linux_on_windows_there_are_automatic/?sort=top